# GuzzleHttp - Send post request while redirecting user to the same page

Tags: php, laravel, payment, guzzle

I am trying to integrate  a site to online payment system.
I have an issue.  I want to send post request to https:/xxx.xx.xx.xx/cgi-bin/cgi_link while redirecting user to the same page. How can i do it ?
I tried to do it by GuzzleHttp, but failed
I want not to show input fields in view side.

```
echo "
    <input name=\"AMOUNT\" value=\"{$db_row['AMOUNT']}\" type=\"hidden\">
    <input name=\"CURRENCY\" value=\"{$db_row['CURRENCY']}\" type=\"hidden\">
    <input name=\"ORDER\" value=\"{$db_row['ORDER']}\" type=\"hidden\">
    <input name=\"DESC\" value=\"{$db_row['DESC']}\" type=\"hidden\">
    <input name=\"MERCH_NAME\" value=\"{$db_row['MERCH_NAME']}\" type=\"hidden\">
    <input name=\"MERCH_URL\" value=\"{$db_row['MERCH_URL']}\" type=\"hidden\">
    <input name=\"TERMINAL\" value=\"{$db_row['TERMINAL']}\" type=\"hidden\">
    <input name=\"EMAIL\" value=\"{$db_row['EMAIL']}\" type=\"hidden\">
    <input name=\"TRTYPE\" value=\"{$db_row['TRTYPE']}\" type=\"hidden\">    
    <input name=\"COUNTRY\" value=\"{$db_row['COUNTRY']}\" type=\"hidden\"> 
    <input name=\"MERCH_GMT\" value=\"{$db_row['MERCH_GMT']}\" type=\"hidden\"> 
    <input name=\"TIMESTAMP\" value=\"{$oper_time}\" type=\"hidden\">
    <input name=\"NONCE\" value=\"{$nonce}\" type=\"hidden\">
    <input name=\"BACKREF\" value=\"{$db_row['BACKREF']}\" type=\"hidden\">
    <input name=\"LANG\" value=\"AZ\" type=\"hidden\">
";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

    try {

        $response = $guzzle->post(env('API_URL'), [
            'form_params' => [
                'param_1' => '{data_1}',
                'param_2' => '{data_2}',
                'param_3' => '{data_3}',
                'param_4' => '{data_4}',
                'param_5' => '{data_5}'
            ],
        ]);

        if(isset($response) && $response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // do something
        }

    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {

        // do something

    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {

        // do something

    }

    return response;
```